# Performance degradation in built-in aura components

Tags: aura

Any idea what might be causing this?

```
aura_proddebug.js:50199 WARNING: [Performance degradation] markup://aura:if ["183:0"] in force:access ["156:0"] needed to clear unrendered body.
More info: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/perf_warnings_if.htm
Component hierarchy: [one:one]>[force:access]

aura_proddebug.js:50199 WARNING: [Performance degradation] markup://aura:if ["263:0;p"] in one:header ["81:0;p"] needed to clear unrendered body.
More info: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/perf_warnings_if.htm
Component hierarchy: [one:one]>[laf:appLayoutHost]>[laf:standardLayoutContainer]>[one:header]
```

Answer (score 0):

From this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/perf_warnings_if.htm?search_text=aura:if):

> This warning occurs when you change the `isTrue` attribute of an
>   `<aura:if>` tag from `true` to `false` in the same rendering cycle. The
>   unrendered body of the `<aura:if>` must be destroyed, which is avoidable
>   work for the framework that slows down rendering time.

Comment: Yes, I had seen that, but these are written by and provided by Salesforce!

Comment: If you're sure about that, than I wouldn't worry about it. There's not much you can do about it (unless you work at Salesforce and that's your job). And if there's not a whole lot of them than I don't think your going to notice the performance difference anyway. I think Salesforce is in the process of moving their Aura components to Lightning Web Components so these messages should disappear at some point.